# Java via unix, pass in arguments instead of hard coded strings

Tags: java, database, string, unix, args

I have the following script (cleaned as it may have sensitive stuff like connection strings in it) 
and it works, it works fairly well, the only thing I'm worried about is having the DB user name and password hard coded in there, I've tried to figure out how to pass in strings as I execute it, but with no joy.

```
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class map_check {
  private static final String CONNECT = "ConnectionString goes here";
  private static final String Query1 = "SELECT 1 \n"+
                                       " , 2 \n"+
                                       " , 3 \n"+
                                       " , 4 \n"+
                                       " , 5 \n"+
                                       " , 6 \n"+
                                       " , 7 \n"+
                                       " , 8  \n"+
                                       "FROM db.tab.log \n"+
                                       "where   CONVERT(VARCHAR(19),StartTime,104)  \n"+
                                       "= CONVERT(VARCHAR(19),GETDATE(),104) \n"+
                                       "order by starttime asc";
  private static final String SQLUSER = "**SCOTT**";
  private static final String SQLPSWD = "**TIGER**";

  public static void main(String[] paramArrayOfString) {
    try {
      Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException localClassNotFoundException1) {
      System.out.print("ClassNotFoundException: ");
      System.out.println(localClassNotFoundException1.getMessage());
      System.exit(2);
    }

    try {
      Connection SQL_CONN = DriverManager.getConnection(CONNECT, SQLUSER, SQLPSWD);

      Statement SQL_Stmt = SQL_CONN.createStatement();
      ResultSet SQL_RS = SQL_Stmt.executeQuery(Query1);
      String format = "%-40s%s%n";
      System.out.println("1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8");
      while (SQL_RS.next()) {
        System.out.println(SQL_RS.getString("1")+","+
                           SQL_RS.getString("2")+","+
                           SQL_RS.getString("3")+","+
                           SQL_RS.getString("4")+","+
                           SQL_RS.getString("5")+","+
                           SQL_RS.getString("6")+","+
                           SQL_RS.getString("7")+","+
                           SQL_RS.getString("8"));
      }

      SQL_Stmt.close();
      SQL_CONN.close();

      System.exit(0);
    } catch (SQLException localSQLException) {
      System.err.println("SQLException: " + localSQLException.getMessage());
    }
  }
}
```

I think i'm doing it all backwards, should I be dimming them inside the next "try"?

Comment: What exactly is your problem in passing your strings? When you execute your program via command line, you can give space separated arguments and they'll be given to your main methods String[] in the order you provided in the command line. You can access them based on the param index. Is that not what you want to do? Pardon me, but it's not exactly clear on what's needed here. Also, what do you mean by dimming?

Comment: How about `DriverManager.getConnection(CONNECT, paramArrayOfString[0], paramArrayOfString[1])` though I would just call it`args`

Comment: Apologies, I'm new to Java, I'm trying to get the class to take in SQLUSER = "**SCOTT**" and SQLPSWD = "**TIGER**", but as args[0] and args[1], that I can call when I run this? I run it with java -cp jtds-1.2.2.jar:. class_name, and would like to do something like java -cp jtds-1.2.2.jar:. map_check "SCOTT" "TIGER", bit I seem to be doing it wrong :/

Comment: Thanks @PeterLawrey, I've changed this now, but i'm getting errors on the compile, saying "map_check_new.java:23: missing method body, or declare abstract
  public static void main(String[] paramArrayOfString[]);
                     ^

Comment: @BenCoughlan You have messed up the syntax. I suggest you stick to the common pattern of `public static void main(String[] args) {` until you are more confident.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a million @Peter Lawrey - I get what you were saying now, Answer is below, Really appreciate it, not finding java easy at all!

```
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class map_check_new {
  private static final String MAPCONNECT = "connstring";
  private static final String Query1 = "SELECT 1 \n"+
                                       " , 2 \n"+
                                       " , 3 \n"+
                                       " , 4 \n"+
                                       " , 5 \n"+
                                       " , 6 \n"+
                                       " , 7 \n"+
                                       " , 8  \n"+
                                       "FROM db.tab.audit \n"+
                                       "where   CONVERT(VARCHAR(19),StartTime,104)  \n"+
                                       "= CONVERT(VARCHAR(19),GETDATE(),104) \n"+
                                       "order by starttime asc";
  public static void main(String[] args) {
 try {
      Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException localClassNotFoundException1) {
      System.out.print("ClassNotFoundException: ");
      System.out.println(localClassNotFoundException1.getMessage());
      System.exit(2);
    }

    try {
      Connection SQL_CONN = DriverManager.getConnection(CONNECT, args[0], args[1]);

      Statement SQL_Stmt = SQL_CONN.createStatement();
      ResultSet SQL_RS = SQL_Stmt.executeQuery(Query1);
      String format = "%-40s%s%n";
      System.out.println("1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8");
      while (SQL_RS.next()) {
        System.out.println(SQL_RS.getString("1")+","+
                           SQL_RS.getString("2")+","+
                           SQL_RS.getString("3")+","+
                           SQL_RS.getString("4")+","+
                           SQL_RS.getString("5")+","+
                           SQL_RS.getString("6")+","+
                           SQL_RS.getString("7")+","+
                           SQL_RS.getString("8"));
      }

      SQL_Stmt.close();
      SQL_CONN.close();

      System.exit(0);
    } catch (SQLException localSQLException) {
      System.err.println("SQLException: " + localSQLException.getMessage());
    }
  }
}
```